# Executing Dynamic Native SQL with Oracle Table type gives invalid identifier error

Tags: sql, oracle, dynamic, types, procedure

We have created Oracle Table type. And we have created an array of it. This is done as we dont know how many values can come which may be too much for a IN clause in sql query.

--Code Snippet -----

```
create or replace 
TYPE "INPUTCODE" 
as object
(pc varchar2(100) )

create or replace 
TYPE "INPUTCODEARR" 
    IS TABLE OF inputcode;

create or replace 
PROCEDURE "TEST_PROC" (testCodes IN inputcodeArr, timeHorizon IN NUMBER, p_recordset OUT SYS_REFCURSOR)
AS
var_sqlStmt VARCHAR2(4096);
BEGIN
var_sqlStmt := 'select t.a,t.b, t.c';
var_sqlStmt := var_sqlStmt || 'from test t';

if testCodes is not null then 
    var_sqlStmt := var_sqlStmt || ', table(testCodes) tc';
        var_sqlStmt := var_sqlStmt || 'where tc.pc = t.name';
end if; 
dbms_output.put_line('Final SQL Statement::' || var_sqlStmt);
open p_recordset for var_sqlStmt;
END TEST_PROC;
```

All the above ones are compiles and when you run the TEST_PROC procedure with few testCode values it will fail with error Invalid identifier for testCodes.

In the procedure, final sql statement which is printing in my console is correct and when you run this as a static sql statement inside procedure it runs without any error. But inside the dynamic sql it fails. 
I tried executing using DYNAMIC_SQL package, but it results in same error. 
Also, i tried giving it as a bind variable for 'table(testCodes)'. That also failed.

Please suggest.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using [dynamic SQL](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e25519/dynamic.htm#CACDDACH), so you *must* tell Oracle which word is an identifier and which word is a variable.

Consider the following statement running directly in SQLPlus:

```
select t.a,t.b, t.c from test t, table(testCodes) tc
```

It will fail because no object is named `testCodes` in your DB. You have to tell the SQL engine that `testCodes` is in fact a variable. You have to do this because you have *chosen* to use dynamic SQL whereas variable binding is automatic in static SQL.

In most cases, you can bind "object" variables in the same way as standard variables. In PL/SQL there are several ways to do this, for instance with cursors you would use `USING`:

```
SQL> DECLARE
  2     l_cur SYS_REFCURSOR;
  3     l_tab inputcodeArr := inputcodeArr(INPUTCODE('A'), INPUTCODE('B'));
  4     l_obj varchar2(100);
  5  BEGIN
  6     OPEN l_cur FOR 'SELECT pc FROM TABLE(:my_variable)' -- notice the ":"
  7        USING l_tab; -- binding by position
  8     LOOP
  9        FETCH l_cur
 10           INTO l_obj;
 11        EXIT WHEN l_cur%NOTFOUND;
 12        dbms_output.put_line(l_obj);
 13     END LOOP;
 14     CLOSE l_cur;
 15  END;
 16  /

A
B

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed
```

In your case however I wouldn't bother with dynamic SQL since you can open a cursor conditionally:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE "TEST_PROC"(testCodes   IN inputcodeArr,
                                        timeHorizon IN NUMBER,
                                        p_recordset OUT SYS_REFCURSOR) AS
BEGIN
   IF testCodes IS NOT NULL THEN
      OPEN p_recordset FOR
         SELECT t.a, t.b, t.c FROM test t, TABLE(testCodes) tc 
          WHERE tc.pc = t.NAME;
   ELSE
      OPEN p_recordset FOR
         SELECT t.a, t.b, t.c FROM test t;
   END IF;
END TEST_PROC;
```

My advice would be to stick with static SQL as long as possible, as it's a lot easier to make mistakes with dynamic SQL.

---

Update following comment:

If your number of input is not constant and you have to use dynamic SQL because there are many combinations of filters, you can use the following strategy:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE "TEST_PROC"(testCodes   IN inputcodeArr,
                                        timeHorizon IN NUMBER,
                                        p_recordset OUT SYS_REFCURSOR) AS
   l_sql LONG := 'SELECT t.a, t.b, t.c FROM test t WHERE';
BEGIN
   -- filter #1
   IF testCodes IS NOT NULL THEN
      l_sql := l_sql || ' t.name IN (SELECT pc FROM TABLE(:filter1))';
   ELSE
      l_sql := l_sql || ' :filter1 IS NULL';
   END IF;
   -- filter #2
   IF timeHorizon IS NOT NULL THEN
      l_sql := l_sql || ' AND t.horizon = :filter2';
   ELSE
      l_sql := l_sql || ' AND :filter2 IS NULL';
   END IF;
   -- open cursor
   OPEN p_recordset FOR l_sql USING testCodes, timeHorizon;
END TEST_PROC;
/
```

I'm making sure that the final SQL will always have the same number of variables in the same order, however each condition where the filter is NULL will be a tautology (`NULL IS NULL`).

Comment: BI agree with your point. But I cannot use the second approach as you have suggested because i have around 7 inputs which can come this way. So number of combinations becomes too much. I tried by changing the code like this as you have mentioned.                            if testCodes is not null then 
    var_sqlStmt := var_sqlStmt || ', table(:vtest) tc';
        var_sqlStmt := var_sqlStmt || 'where tc.pc = t.name';
end if;         open p_recordset for var_sqlStmt using 'testCodes';   This did not replace variable and got error.

Comment: Agreed, in your case you'll have to use dynamic SQL. I'll update my answer to show how you can still use the general principle of using when the number of input variables is not constant.

Comment: Again we are using IN clause which we wanted to avoid (As there is a limitation of 1000 items) and hence we used oracle type tables. Also, i am using Table(:filter1), but it is not replacing the bind variables at runtime for me with that kind of code.

Comment: Sorry Vincent. bind variable part is working. I will check and get back to you. Thanks

Comment: The limitation of the `IN` clause if for the [static SQL condition only](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/conditions013.htm#i1050801). Here i'm using `IN` with a subquery so there is no such limitation, in fact I've just rewritten your join condition as a semi-join (hopefully joins and semi-joins don't have cardinal limitations :).